# Is it possible to generate new lat-lng using lat-lng & distance (Reverse to calculate distance between 2 lat-lng)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3, rssi

I am receiving data like below from BLE devices.

```
"payload": [
        {
            "r": -90,
            "t": "1970-01-18T10:30:17.823Z"
        },
        {
            "r": -80,
            "t": "1970-01-18T10:30:17.833Z"
        },
        {
            "r": -70,
            "t": "1970-01-18T10:30:17.843Z"
        }
    ]
```

r is rssi. we will assuming a distance out of these numbers(rssi). I have lat-lng of BLE device.

We can calculate distance between two lat-lng using mathematical formula. I want reverse formula.

So if i have one lat-lng & a distance. Can i calculate next point(lat-lng) using distance & starting point(lat-lng). Direction does not matter.

So basically what i want is formula like **lat2-lng2 = lat1-lng1 (some formula) distance** like below

```
function(lat1, lng1, distance){
    /////some calculaitons to calculate lat2 & lng2
    return {'lat2' :lat2, 'lng2' : lng2};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with Google Maps JavaScript API, you could use the [`computeOffset`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) function, which accepts an initial position, distance, and heading determining the direction of the displacement. For example

```
    var ret = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(
        new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 1000, 0);

    console.log(ret.lat(), ret.lng());
```

This should return a position with zero longitude and latitude corresponding to 1/R radians (R representing the radius of Earth within the spherical model)

Alternatively, you could implement the formula directly: http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm#LL

Comment: I have to use it on server(API) side. So google maps api will not work. I'll test direct formula though. Thanks.